# What are the degrees of freedom for "linear regression t-test" with one binary variable?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, linear

Quick, simple question.

I read that DF = n-2 when doing "a linear regression t-test" with a continuous independent variable.  (Testing that the slope is 0).
https://stattrek.com/regression/slope-test.aspx

I want to manually run through this with a single binary independent variable.

Is DF still n-2?

BTW, the "linear regression t-test" proceeds with t = b<sub>1</sub>/SE, which are provided from lm() - using R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that you subtract a degree of freedom for each coefficient that is estimated before calculating the standard deviation.  So for a one sample t-test you estimate a single mean so $df=n-1$.  In simple linear regression you estimate a single slope and y-intercept, so $df=n-2$.

A single binary predictor is usually coded as an indicator variable (0/1), so your regression most likely estimates an intercept (mean for baseline level) and a single slope (difference in means), so that would be 2 parameters estimated and $df=n-2$.  If you use a categorical predictor with more than 2 categories, then that will spend more degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thanks.  (It is giving an intercept and a single slope).